# Posthog SQL performance (properties access)

Tags: sql, clickhouse, posthog

Our PostHog instance works with huge data (~100 mln events).
If I use a HogQL query that uses event properties, then it takes too long time ("Estimated query execution time is too long").
How too deal with properties in PostHog properly to improve performance of clickhouse?

[image: error]

I tried to rewrite SQL queries, but even the simplest ones that use event properies fails.